# edgeAgent continues to "connect" after device is shutdown

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

Mind blown, as I think this shows that the Azure IOT Hub connects to the device to get the logs.  The timestamp is after I unplugged the device for at least an hour (to ensure that cloud caught up).

How is this possible?
[image]

I'm having a problem in that the device is reporting both edgeAgent and edgeHub are both running, and the device is turned off.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the mystery is solved.  My EFLOW VM was provisioned with a DeviceID that was responding. As the VM is very much hidden from the Hypervisor, and the device ID is not easy to find, all contributed to an error that caused me almost 2 days of errors in which the hidden device was causing external device errors.

Posting this to help anyone with a similar issue.  If you want to know the device id, you have to review config.toml in the **/etc/aziot**

Referenced here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/configure-device?view=iotedge-1.4